# RobotFramework: Variable '${username}' not found

Tags: python, selenium, variables, robotframework

I just wanna ask for some help with this error. I really can't fix it.

This is the new error I have encountered:  **Keyword 'Login process' expected 2 arguments, got 4.**

I am using python 2.7.17. Please help me. Thank you very much!

*login_resources.robot*

```
     *** Settings ***
     Library     SeleniumLibrary
    
     *** Variables ***
     ${url}      https://sampleemail.com
     ${browser}      chrome
     ${username}
     ${password}

    *** Keywords ***
      Open my Browser
          Open browser    ${url}     ${browser}
          maximize browser window

      Closing browser
          close all browsers

      Enter username
          BuiltIn.Sleep   3
          
          [Arguments]    ${username}
          input text      name:email    ${username}


      Enter password
          [Arguments]    ${password}
          input text      name:password    ${password}


      Click login
          click element    xpath://*[@id="root"]/main/div/form/button/span[1]
```

*login_testcase.robot*

```
      *** Settings ***
       Library   SeleniumLibrary
       Resource    ../Resources/login_resources.robot
       Library     DataDriver   ../TestData/sample.xlsx   sheet_name=Sheet1

       Suite Setup       Open my Browser
       Suite Teardown    Closing browser
       Test Template     Login process


       *** Test Cases ***


       Login test    using       ${username}      ${password}


       *** Keywords ***
       Login process
           [Arguments]     ${username}     ${password}
           Enter username     ${username}
           Enter password    ${password}
           Click login
```

Comment: i dont see any declaration of ${username} or ${password}. Where do you declare them?

Comment: Hi Jiri, I tried to declare the ${username} and ${password} variable like this one:                    
        *** Variables ***
        ${url}      https://sampleemail.com
        ${browser}      chrome
        ${username}
        ${password}
 but still got this error: Keyword 'Login process' expected 2 arguments, got 4.

Comment: can you update your question, so that it is with the new declaration?

Comment: The title mentions one error, the body of the question asks about another. Which one are you asking about? Also, this code does not give the error you say it does. It gives the error `Keyword 'Login process' expected 2 arguments, got 3.`, which is correct. It's getting the arguments `using`, `${username}`, and `${password}`.